# Proper design technique

Tags: oop, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an asp.net mvc4 application that will ask the user a set of questions based on a particular criteria that they enter. Each question is stored in a table and only those questions that meet the criteria will be displayed to the end user.

I am using a viewmodel that combines information from a couple of different tables. Basically it has a list of Questions and an inspection id to tie all the test together. My question is what is the proper oo design technique for populating the viewmodel.

Should the method / methods for populating the viewmodel reside within the viewmodel class itself? Basically passing the entities into the viewmodel and allow it to populate itself.

Should there be a new class that you send in the entities in and it returns the viewmodel?

Or is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, your approach is valid.

Consider the following example in your model:

```
public List<Questions> Questions
{ 
get {
     QuestionRepository Rep = new QuestionRepository();
     return Rep.ObtainQuestions(ClientAge,ClientType)
     }
 }

public int ClientAge { get; set; }
public ClientTypeEnum ClientType { get; set; }
```

the getter in the Questions property includes all the logic. as long as the clientAge and the ClientType properties have valid values, the question list will be populated. this avoids having to set the data in every action method where you need to populate the property.

in the example I am getting the data from a repository but you could get it from an ORM like entity framework, or any other source.

you can google the term skinny controllers and read up more on the recomendations and best practices.